# What does this code do ? (About pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code and im stuck at second line

```
unsigned long check_password(const char* p){
    int* ip = (int*)p;
    int i;
    int res=0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        res += ip[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

`int* ip = (int*)p;` What does this line mean ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1870232) might be helpful.

Comment: It looks horribly broken.

Comment: This code defines new pointer to `int` type from pointer to `char`.

Comment: Looks a lot like C, not C++. Reason: only primitive types, C-style cast, `i` declared before used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned long check_password(const char* p){
    int* ip = (int*)p; // line 2, non-const not required
    int i;
    int res=0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        res += ip[i]; // line 6
    }
    return res;
}
```

Line 2 declares `ip` as a pointer to integer and initializes it to `(int*)p`. `(int*)p` is a C-style cast, which is in this case resolved to `reinterpret_cast<int*>(const_cast<char*>(p))`. See

[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

`ip` now points to the memory location of p. When using `ip`, the memory at that location is interpreted as holding an integer, even though it holds a char; and it can be modified, even though it was initially declared const.

Line 6 treats `ip` as if it was pointing to the first element of an array of `int` and adds the `i`th element of that array to `res`. It's likely that `ip` actually points to the first element of an array of `char`. That means, that each iteration `sizeof(int)` consecutive elements of that array are interpreted as the representation of a single `int`.

The intention of this code is probably, that a sequence of 5 `int`s is passed as an array of `char` of length `sizeof(int)*5`.

Note that this code is UB if `p` doesn't actually point to memory of a size of at least `sizeof(int)*5`, since the memory in that region is read. I.e. the `char`-array must be at least of length `sizeof(int)*5`.

Casting away the const in your code is not required

```
unsigned long check_password(const char* p){
    const int* ip = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(p);
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        res += ip[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> int* ip = (int*)p; What does this line mean ?

It means, "create a pointer to integers which starts at the same address as p."

The function is expecting p to be pointing to a sequence of bytes that represents 5 integers.

**The behaviour of this function is only defined if p really was pointing to a sequence of integers before being cast to a** `const char*`

In practice, the author of this code is assuming:

1. That the sequence of bytes has been encoded in such a way that they truly represent 5 integers on this machine (taking into account word size and endian-ness of the architecture).
2. that the alignment of the address represented by p is correct for addressing memory as integers (some processors have restrictions in this regard).

It's probably not code you want to copy or learn from, other than as a cautionary tale.